# keras model.fit_generator error.how do i solve this issue?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have checked documentation for keras.fit_generator function still not able to find the problem
 Libraries are working fine in my laptop
My code:

```
# train the network
print("training network...")
sys.stdout.flush()
#class_mode ='categorical', # 2D one-hot encoded labels
H = model.fit_generator(aug.flow(Xtrain, trainY,batch_size=BS),
                    validation_data=(Xval, valY),
                    steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS,
                    epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1)

# save the model to disk
print("Saving model to disk")
sys.stdout.flush()
model.save("/tmp/mymodel")
```

i am getting following error for my code :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File 
"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\my_root\lib\site- 
 packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
File "<ipython-input-80-935b20410c11>", line 8, in <module>
epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\my_root\lib\site- 
packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\my_root\lib\site- 
packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1418, in fit_generator

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\my_root\lib\site- 
packages\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 162, in fit_generator

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\my_root\lib\site- 
packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 647, in __init__

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\my_root\lib\site- 
packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 433, in __init__


File"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\
my_root\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 133, in Value

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\
my_root\lib\multiprocessing\sharedctypes.py", line 182 
exec template % ((name,)*7) in d
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I think this is a problem with your python installation, because you seem to be using python 3, yet the multiprocessing package has python2 code.

Comment: Thanks. the  error was caused due to some environment error in anaconda. 
reinstalling anaconda solved my problem.